# Adding buttons to sencha Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: button, extjs, render, treepanel

**Situation:**

My view has a `tabpanel` with 2 containers containing a `treePanel`.
Some rows in the `treePanel` have to contain buttons.

To add buttons to the `treeGrid` I use `render()`:

Example:

```
var feedbackButtons =  new Array("Ok", "Cancel");
var buttonText = '';
line.set(gridView.m_columnIds[i], '<div id="test" ></div>');

line.commit();

for (var nr in feedbackButtons) {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button',
    {
        text: feedbackButtons[nr],
        lineId: lineId,
        gridView: gridView,
        style: {
            display: 'inline-block',
            marginRight: '3px',
            backgroundColor: '#743'
        },
        handler: gridView._onButtonClicked
    }).render(document.body, 'test');
}
```

**Problems:**

Adding a row to an inactive (not shown) `treePanel` is resulting in a button with a height of 0px.

Screenshot:
http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3492/sencha.png

**Current workaround:**

Currently I'm ussing css to fix it:

```
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet('button { height: 16px!important; } \n', null);
```

Has anyone a solution for this problem.

I assume it is a bug!